# dynamic thymeleaf list as dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Sorry, my knowledge in this section is so bad... maybe it's a simple thing. I  build a dynamic list with thymeleaf like this (this works):
[html/thymeleaf code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSszC.jpg) (code is also at the end of the post)

So how is it possible (is it possible at all) to make every single list entry as a clickble "line" and when I click on one it should show the detail content of the list entry below (like a drop-down). The details for each entry is an other dynamic list. The first click open, second close the details. By the way... I don't use JQuery just JS, java, html, css and thymeleaf.

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Phasen Name</th>
      <th>PC</th>
      <th>AC</th>
      <th>EV</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="Projectphase : ${evaPhasen}">
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getphasenname()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getplannedValue()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getactualCost()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getearnedValue()}"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Thx for your help and answers!
Manuel

Comment: done... hope its like it should! sorry for first try

Comment: Should we modify this question title, to speak about table and accordion in plain javascript ? IMO this is the core question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you are trying to implement an `accordion`, this need a bit of javascript.

Main idea is : toggling displaying of a detail row which is below the current row (`display : none <-> display : table-row`). This is done with an EventListener attached to the first `td` of each row (`class='accordion'`).

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(this.parentElement.nextElementSibling)
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "table-row") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "table-row";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse : collapse;
}

td, th {
  border : 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Phasen Name</th>
      <th>PC</th>
      <th>AC</th>
      <th>EV</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="accordion">Phasename 1 (See Details)</td>
      <td>PC1</td>
      <td>AC1</td>
      <td>EV1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none"><td colspan="4">Here are the details 1</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="accordion">Phasename 2 (See Details)</td>
      <td>PC2</td>
      <td>AC2</td>
      <td>EV2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none"><td colspan="4">Here are the details 2</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Note that with Thymeleaf, the static HTML (written to give you a runnable snippet) would be replaced by :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Phasen Name</th>
    <th>PC</th>
    <th>AC</th>
    <th>EV</th>
  </tr>
  <th:block th:each="Projectphase : ${evaPhasen}"
    <tr>
      <td class="accordion" th:text="${Projectphase.getphasenname()} (see details)"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getphasenname()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getplannedValue()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getactualCost()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${Projectphase.getearnedValue()}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none"><td colspan="4">Here are the details 1</td></tr>
  </th:block>
</table>
```

Note the use of `th:block` to get 2 `<tr>` for a single ProjectPhase (see : [th:block Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag))

Accordion largely inspired from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp)

Comment: Thx for the answer and it looks already very nice but I would like to have the Phase Name as "link" for the details if this is possible or the button should be after the table (for each line). Second question is about the detail content. Is it possible to show the content from details under the table and not in the table?

Comment: So you want some Ajax loading ?

Comment: I dont know sorry... I'm really a beginner in this stuff! Each line of the dynamic generated list should be a link (or just the phasename, doesn't matter to me) and the phasename should be the ID for the detail content to get the right one active. Then the details should be insert under the selected row but without columns (100% wide)

Comment: Does it look better now ?

Comment: nice! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much for your help!